# Adding Authorization Header to WebSocket in React Electron App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, websocket, electron

I'm attempting to connect to a third party secure websocket that uses Bearer Auth via Header from what I've been told. Based off of most answers here and elsewhere setting headers isn't something that's supported via the WebSockets. How would I go about doing this in React within an Electron App? I'm using the 'react-use-websocket' package but at this stage and open to any component centric solution.

I've tried the following configurations in an attempt to send the header or provide Auth with my JWT but repeatedly receive `HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available` when attempting to open a connection, and the connection subsequently closes.

```
const [socketUrl, setSocketUrl] = useState('wss://My.JWT.Token@messaging.thirdPartyService.com/?access_token=My.JWT.Token');

const [socketUrl, setSocketUrl] = useState('wss://messaging.thirdPartyService.com/?access_token=My.JWT.Token');

const { sendMessage, sendJsonMessage, lastMessage, readyState } = useWebSocket(socketUrl, {
        headers: {
            ['Authorization']: "Bearer " + "My.JWT.Token",
        }});
```

I'm absolutely at my wits end and would love some help in figuring out a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue recently and after a lot of research, I found that You currently can't add Authorization headers to a Websocket URL in Javascript.
The closest you can do is to pass in the access_token as a query param as you did here:

```
const [socketUrl, setSocketUrl] = useState('wss://messaging.thirdPartyService.com/?access_token=My.JWT.Token');
```

To do this though, the API would have to change the structure to take in the token from the query parameters.

You can check [this thread](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/467#issuecomment-77828446) for more info.